# PHP phantom cron job

Tags: debian, cron, php

I disabled all my cron jobs by putting a `#` in front of them. Except for one:

```
@reboot echo "Hi I rebooted"
```

The rest are:

```
#0 2,14 * * * /home/backup1/mysql-backup.sh
#0 * * * * mono /root/apps/AlertAuth.exe
```

However, my inbox gets this message

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/suhosin.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/suhosin.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

with the subject:

> Cron  [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && find /var/lib/php5/ -type f -cmin +$(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) -print0 | xargs -n 200 -r -0 rm

I don't have any cron jobs.

Maybe the `init.d` script I have for PHP is causing this? Or maybe how do I fix this? I tried reinstalling PHP5, it seems to work yet that file `.so` doesn't exist.

Comment: Are you sure no cronjobs are installed? PHP package on Debian installs some stuff in `/etc/cron.d/php5` I believe. Its purpose is to remove old temporary files like session files. Also, let's take a step back, and explain what you're trying to accomplish/fix here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debian's cron, like many other modern variants, read jobs in files under directories called `/etc/cron.d`, `/etc/cron.hourly`, etc., in addition to the traditional `/etc/crontab`. In particular, the job you see comes from `/etc/cron.d/php5` which is installed by the [php5-common](http://packages.debian.org/php5-common) package.